# No file upload on php built-in web server

Tags: php, html, forms, webserver

I have the following html form:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
   Name: <input type="text" name="file_name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload">
</form>
```

But the file never gets uploaded. The text field is just there as debug code.

The following php code:

```
  <?php
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo "</pre>";
  ?>
```

Gives the following output when I fill all the forms values:

> Array (
>
> [file_name] => abc
>
> [action] => Upload )

And I'm running a php server as follows:

> php -nS localhost:8000 -t .

Am I doing anything wrong here? It's all running locally and the file I'm uploading is less than 10 bytes long.

Comment: Try getting the file with $_FILES

Comment: The file information should be located in the [$_FILES superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Comment: PHP won't upload the file for you. You have to tell it to upload the file. Also, grab it with $_FILES to be able to upload it.

Comment: @tdoggy I had code to upload before, this was only debug stuff. The problem was with _POST -> _FILES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find your data about the uploaded file in this variable: `$_FILES["file"]` and not in the `$_POST` variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that PHP is configured to allow file uploads.

In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On:

file_uploads = On

Comment: I was using the -n option on the web server, it ignores any php.ini file.